# Generalisation of the notion of correlation for $\alpha$-stable distributions

Tags: correlation, quantiles, stable-distribution

Pearson correlation is defined via variance and covariance, so will not work when applied to $\alpha$-stable distributions with $\alpha \neq 2$. Is there a way to generalise the notion of correlation to such distributions, e.g. by doing some form of renormalisation?

Example:

$$
\rho_{generalised}(X, Y) := \lim_{k \to \infty} \rho(X_k, Y_k)
$$

where $X_k := \min(\max(X, -k), k)$ and $Y_k$ similarly.

Comment: Maybe the (population versions) of any rank-correlation measure would also be an idea.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that this limit exists though?

Comment: @MichaelM Like Spearman rho or Kendall tau?

Comment: @StasK I don't know - I asked this question to see if someone already did the hard work ;-)

Comment: Yes. Kendall's tau measures the probability of a concordant pair minus the probability of a discordant pair, the Spearman rank-correlation can also be expressed in terms of the joint distribution.

Comment: So are there bivariate stable distributions, written out explicitly?

Comment: @StasK You could take 2 independent Cauchy distributions $X$ and $Y$ and define $U_1 = X+Y$ and $U_2 = X - Y$. $\vec{U}$ will be a bivariate correlated stable distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found something that could be useful. An alternative to the traditional correlation for $\alpha$-stable distributions with $\alpha > 1$ is the signed symmetric covariation coefficient.

**Definition.** Let $(X_{1},X_{2})$ be a bivariate symmetric $\alpha$-stable random vector with $\alpha > 1$. The signed symmetric covariation coefficient between $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ is the quantity:

$$ scov(X_{1},X_{2}) = \kappa_{(X_{1},X_{2})} | \frac{[X_{1},X_{2}]_{\alpha}[X_{2},X_{1}]_{\alpha}}{|| X_{1}||_{\alpha}^{\alpha} || X_{2}||_{\alpha}^{\alpha}} |^{\frac{1}{2}}, $$

where

- $[X_{1},X_{2}]_{\alpha} = \int_{S_{2}} s_{1}s_{2}^{\langle\alpha -1\rangle} \mathbf{\Gamma}(d\mathbf{s})$, where $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ is the sprectral measure of the random vector $(X_{1},X_{2})$;
- $||X_{1}||_{\alpha} = ([X_{1},X_{1}]_{\alpha})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$;
- $ \kappa_{(X_{1},X_{2})} = sign([X_{1},X_{2}]_{\alpha}) \quad if\quad sign([X_{1},X_{2}]_{\alpha}) = sign([X_{2},X_{1}]_{\alpha})$;
- $ \kappa_{(X_{1},X_{2})} = - 1 \quad if\quad sign([X_{1},X_{2}]_{\alpha}) = - sign([X_{2},X_{1}]_{\alpha})$.

The following proposition shows that the signed symmetric covariation coefficient has desirable properties as does the ordinary correlation coefficient of a bivariate Gaussian random vector.

**Proposition.** Let $(X_{1},X_{2})$ be a bivariate symmetric $\alpha$-stable random vector with $\alpha > 1$. The signed symmetric covariation coefficient has the following properties:

1. $-1 \leq scov(X_{1},X_{2}) \leq 1$
2. if $X_{1},X_{2}$ are independent, then $scov(X_{1},X_{2}) = 0$;
3. $|scov(X_{1},X_{2})| = 1$ if and only if $X_{2} = \lambda X_{1}$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \, \lambda \neq 0$;
4. for $\alpha = 2$, $scov(X_{1},X_{2})$ coincides with the usual correlation coefficient.

For further details refer to: *Estimation and comparison of signed symmetric
covariation coefficient and generalized association
parameter for alpha-stable dependence* by Bernédy Kodia and Bernard Garel
url: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00951885/document

Comment: can  you add the URL for that reference?

Comment: Is $scov$ bi-linear?

Comment: ... sorry, stupid question. Of course it won't be. But it looks like the closest to the Pearson correlation one can get.

Answer (score 4):

I found this idea in the book Gilchrist: "Statistical Modelling with Quantile Functions"; this are based on medians:

The **comedian** (don't laugh) of $X$ and $Y$ is defined by
$$
\text{coMED}(X,Y) = M[(X-M(X))(Y-M(Y))]
$$
where $M(X)$ is the median of $X$.  Then one would have to standardize this by some measures of variability, that book gives **MedAD** as the sample median of the deviations $d_i$ from the median.  How well that works for the stable distribution I do not know; you could investigate it by simulation.

Answer to additional question in the comments: "Do you think comedian is bilinear, like covariance?":  First, the median itself satisfies $M(aX+b)=aM(X)+b$ (assuming that in the even $n$ case we use the mid-median, that is, taking the median of $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ as $\frac{X_{(2)}+X_{(3)}}{2}$ where $X_{(i)}$ denotes the order statistics).  This is because a linear transformation $ax+b$ of the data will not change the order ($a>0$) or will reverse the order ($a<0$). It is the last case which forces the use of the mid-median!  But this is not enough to conclude that the median is linear, we would need that $M(X+Y)=M(X)+M(Y)$ and that is manifestly **false**. So without linearity of the median itself, bilinearity of the comedian is too much to ask. It cannot be true.

Comment: Interesting! I will give it a try.

Comment: Downvoted for suggesting simulations. Stable distributions are not particularly prone to good simulations  -- every sample will have a variance... contrary to what your textbook says that it doesn't.

Comment: @StasK:  OK, but do you have some reference for "Stable distributions are not particularly prone to good simulations", I would be interested.

Comment: That's my gut feeling. Investigate *WHAT* by simulation? In my simulations of how an estimation procedure that I investigate works, I have a known population parameter, I simulate from some distribution that has this parameter somewhere, I estimate my model, rinse, repeat, compute the bias, stability of the standard errors, the mean squared error and coverage of the confidence intervals. I am at a loss as to what to do when the distribution does not have enough moments. May be it's just me.

Comment: @StasK: OK, but when moments do not exist, we can still use quantiles such as the median an IQR and so on.

Comment: @StasK I disagree, I've seen good, stable simulations of Levy or Cauchy distributions.

Comment: OK, I am just too ignorant on this.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Do you think comedian is bilinear, like covariance?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks for the response. Although the other answer seems to be closer to what I was looking for, co-median is also very interesting.