# Meaning of "upper median"

Tags: descriptive-statistics, median

I didn't find a definition for the **upper** median (or lower), but my guess would be the following:

If you have $2n$ samples for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_i$ is the i-th lowest value, the lower median is element $x_{n}$, the upper median is $x_{n+1}$ and the "normal" median is $\frac{x_{n}+x_{n+1}}{2}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Can you explain where you saw this?  I would guess that it means the upper quartile which is the median of the upper half of the data. I never heard it called this before. Also, I have never heard of any names for the $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ that you are describing.

Comment: @John L The "upper quartile" to which you refer has been called (by J. Tukey) the "upper hinge." Referring to it as a median would be inappropriate.  Despite that, Googling indicates your guess is correct.  It also indicates that primarily non-authoritative web sites (such as those devoted to helping schoolchildren) use that terminology!

Comment: @whuber would it be fair to say that these non-authoritative websites were authored by co-medians?

Comment: Or 'mediocrites'

Comment: @Sycorax: NO, you cannot: COmedian is also a technical concept: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165262/generalisation-of-the-notion-of-correlation-for-alpha-stable-distributions/165264#165264